# 2 column CSS layout, but navigation column won't extend to bottom of page

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

The objective is to setup a 2 column CSS layout. The text book in class makes it sound as easy as editing the CSS Nav by making it float left. However, it will not extend the Nav column all the way to the bottom of the page as their example shows, but it does float in the upper left.

CSS:

```
    body{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #666666;
    font: sans-serif;
    background-image: url(background.jpg);
}

header{
    background-color: #000033;
    color: #ffffff;
    font: sans-serif;
}

nav{
    float: left;
    width: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #90c7e3;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
}

main{
    display: block;
}
h1{
    line-height: 200%;
    background-image: url(sunset.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    padding-left: 20px;
    height: 72 px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

h2
{
    color: #3399cc;
    font: serif;
}

h3
{
    color: #000033;
}

dt
{
    color: #000033;
    font-weight: bold;
}

    #resort
{
    color: #000033;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

    #footer
{
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: .7em;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
}

    #wrapper
{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    min-width: 700px;
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000033;
}

    #homehero
{
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url(coast.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

    #yurthero
{
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url(yurt.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

    #trailhero
{
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url(trail.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pacific.css">
    <title>Pacific Trails Resort</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
    <h1>Pacific Trails Resort</h1>
</header>

<nav>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <a href="yurts.html">Yurts</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <a href="activities.html">Activities</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <a href="reservations.html">Reservations</a>
</nav>

<div id="homehero">
</div>

<main>
    <h2>Enjoy Nature in Luxury</h2>
    <p><span class="resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span> offers a special     lodging experience on the California North Coast. Relax in serenity with     panoramic views of the Pacific Ocean.</p>

<ul>
    <li>Private yurts with decks overlooking the ocean</li>
    <li>Activities lodge with fireplace and gift shop</li>
    <li>Nightly fine dining at the Overlook Cafe</li>
    <li>Heated outdoor pool and whirlpool</li>
    <li>Guided hiking tours of the redwoods</li>
</ul>
    <div>
        <span class="resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span><br>
        12010 Pacific Trails Road<br>
        Zephyr, CA 95555<br>
        888-555-5555<br>
    </div>
</main>
<footer>
    <div id="footer">
    Copyright &copy; 2016 Pacific Trails Resort<br>
    </div>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could use float right on the main element and then give the nav a height to extend it to the bottom of the page but I think that your homehero will end up pushing your main element to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in my comment, you can add float right on the main element and then give the nav a height. You'll also need to restrict the width of the main element so that it fits next to the nav.

Check out this snippet to see this:

```css
body{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #666666;
    font: sans-serif;
    background-image: url(background.jpg);
    position: relative;
}

header{
    background-color: #000033;
    color: #ffffff;
    font: sans-serif;
}

nav{
    width: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #90c7e3;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 100%;
}

main{
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
}
h1{
    line-height: 200%;
    background-image: url(sunset.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    padding-left: 20px;
    height: 72 px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

h2
{
    color: #3399cc;
    font: serif;
}

h3
{
    color: #000033;
}

dt
{
    color: #000033;
    font-weight: bold;
}

    #resort
{
    color: #000033;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

    #footer
{
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: .7em;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
}

    #wrapper
{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    min-width: 700px;
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000033;
}

    #homehero
{
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url(coast.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

    #yurthero
{
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url(yurt.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

    #trailhero
{
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url(trail.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pacific.css">
    <title>Pacific Trails Resort</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h1>Pacific Trails Resort</h1>
</header>

<div id="wrapper">
<nav>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <a href="yurts.html">Yurts</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <a href="activities.html">Activities</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <a href="reservations.html">Reservations</a>
</nav>

<main>
    <div id="homehero">
</div>
    <h2>Enjoy Nature in Luxury</h2>
    <p><span class="resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span> offers a special     lodging experience on the California North Coast. Relax in serenity with     panoramic views of the Pacific Ocean.</p>

<ul>
    <li>Private yurts with decks overlooking the ocean</li>
    <li>Activities lodge with fireplace and gift shop</li>
    <li>Nightly fine dining at the Overlook Cafe</li>
    <li>Heated outdoor pool and whirlpool</li>
    <li>Guided hiking tours of the redwoods</li>
</ul>
    <div>
        <span class="resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span><br>
        12010 Pacific Trails Road<br>
        Zephyr, CA 95555<br>
        888-555-5555<br>
    </div>
</main>
</div>
<footer>
    <div id="footer">
    Copyright &copy; 2016 Pacific Trails Resort<br>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I noticed that you had a position absolute on the nav. I ran with that and positioned it relative to the body. I also moved the header and footer out of the wrapper div so that the wrapper only contains your nav and main elements. I moved the home hero into the main element so that it too will be floated right.

By wrapping the main and nav elements only in the wrapper, we can add `height: 100%;` to the nav element to take the full height of the wrapper. If we kept the header and footer in the wrapper, the nav would still be 100% of the height of the wrapper but now it would be too large because it doesn't discount the height of the header and the footer.

One other thing to note is that I removed the `float: left;` on the nav because the `position: absolute;` makes it irrelevant.